# Parametric Construction Via Initializer List

Tags: c++, class, c++11, virtual, header-files

I'm given the following code to develop my own appointment book application:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include "Appointment.h"
#include "OneTime.h"
#include "Daily.h"
#include "Monthly.h"
#include "Yearly.h"
using namespace std;

void checkAppointments(vector<Appointment*>& apptbook){
   // STATEMENTS
}
void addAppointment(vector<Appointment*>& apptbook){
  // STATEMENTS
}


int main(){

  vector<Appointment*> apptbook;

  char option;

  do {
     cout << "********** Appointment Book Application ************" << endl<< endl;
     cout << "(a) See all appointments on a given day." << endl;
     cout << "(b) Add an appointment." << endl << endl;
     cout << "Enter an option or 'q' to quit: ";

     cin >> option;
     switch(option){
        case 'a': 
            checkAppointments(apptbook);
            break;
        case 'b':
            addAppointment(apptbook);
             break;
        case 'q':
             break;
        default:
            cout << "You entered an invalid option.  Try again!";    
     }
     cout << endl;
  }
  while(option != 'q');

  // Cleaning up 

  for(int i = 0; i < apptbook.size(); i++){
    delete apptbook[i];
  }
  apptbook.clear();

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

I'm asked to use some of the parameters of the below specified `Appointment` constructor to construct the `date` member it the `Appointment` class contained in `Appointment.h` file:

```
Appointment(string description, int month, int day, int yr, int hr, int min)
```

Here is what I've done so far in `Appointment.h` *vis-a-vis* defining the constructor in the requested way:

```
#ifndef APPOINTMENT_H
#define APPOINTMENT_H

#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

class Appointment{

  public:
    Appointment(string description, int month, int day, int yr, int hr, int min);
    Date date;

  private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    string convertInt( int number ) const;
};
Appointment(string description, int month, int day, int yr, int hr, int min) : public date(month, day, yr)
{
    this->description = description;
}
string Appointment::convertInt( int number ) const
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}

#endif
```

I suppose my question goes something like this: "How do I use some of `Appointment`'s parameters to construct the date member it its initializer list?" This concept is new to me, and I'm having some trouble. Here is the `Date.h` and `Date.cpp`:

**Date.h**

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Date{

  public:
    Date(int month, int day, int year);

    int getMonth() const;
    int getDay() const; 
    int getYear() const;

  private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

#endif
```

**Date.cpp**

```
#include "Date.h"
#include<string>
using namespace std;

Date::Date(int month, int day, int year) {
    this->month = month; 
    this->day = day;
    this->year = year;
}

int Date::getMonth() const{
  return month;
}

int Date::getDay() const{
  return day;
}

int Date::getYear() const{
  return year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the **public** keyword from the Appointment constructer
and why did you put the function defintion in the header file?

```
#ifndef APPOINTMENT_H
#define APPOINTMENT_H

#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

class Appointment{

  public:
    Appointment(string description, int month, int day, int yr, int hr, int min);
    Date date;

  private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    string convertInt( int number ) const;
};
Appointment(string description, int month, int day, int yr, int hr, int min) : date(month, day, yr)
{
    this->description = description;
}
string Appointment::convertInt( int number ) const
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor definition is wrong:

```
Appointment(string description, int month, int day, int yr, int hr, int min) : public date(month, day, yr)
{
    this->description = description;
}
```

You should add `Appointement::` as a prefix and remove the `public` keyword there:

```
Appointment::Appointment(string description, int month, int day, int yr, int hr, int min) : date(month, day, yr)
{
    this->description = description;
}
```

Also, please learn to use the `std::` prefix instead of blindly add `using namespace std;`. That's not what namespaces are there for.

Another potential problem arises when you are using dynamic allocation for the vector in:

```
vector<Appointment*> apptbook;
```

There's no need for that. You can just use:

```
std::vector<Appointment> apptbook;
```

and populate it in `addAppointment` like this:

```
void addAppointment(std::vector<Appointment>& apptbook){
    // calculate arguments
    apptbook.emplace_back(description, month, day, yr, hr, min);
}
```

In this way you can get rid of the useless:

```
for(int i = 0; i < apptbook.size(); i++){
    delete apptbook[i];
}
apptbook.clear();
```

altogether.

But if you really need to use dynamic allocation in this case, at least learn to use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (in this order).